# What is causing this file input to be hidden when this class is applied?

Tags: css

I have been playing around trying to get a nice looking drag and drop control on my site and have come across this upload control.

[MDBootstrap File Upload](https://mdbootstrap.com/snippets/jquery/temp/1028828?action=prism_export)

I have found out that removing the class named 'file-field' will cause the normal file input to show.

My question is, what is it that is causing the file input control to dissapear when this class is reapplied, as when I remove all styles from the class using Chrome DevTools by unticking them, it makes no difference.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the Chrome developer tools, you can inspect the element and you will see the styles involved.[image]

Here is a snippet using the CSS styles involved to get that effect, by removing the class 'file-field' the control will show because the current css styles are applying opacity 0, making it transparent within a fancy-styled button.

```css
.md-form {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 1.5rem;
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.btn {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12);
    padding: .84rem 2.14rem;
    font-size: .81rem;
    transition: color .15s ease-in-out,background-color .15s ease-in-out,border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
    margin: .375rem;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: .125rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    white-space: normal;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    color: inherit;
}

.btn-mdb-color {
    background-color: #59698d!important;
    color: #fff;
}
.btn-rounded {
    border-radius: 10em;
}
.waves-effect {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
.float-left {
    float: left!important;
}

.file-field {
    position: relative
}

.file-field .file-path-wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 10px;
    height: 2.5rem
}

.file-field input.file-path {
    width: 100%;
    height: 36px
}

.file-field .btn {
    float: left
}

.file-field span {
    cursor: pointer
}

.file-field input[type=file] {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0
}

.file-field input[type=file]::-webkit-file-upload-button {
    display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="md-form">
  <div class="file-field">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div class="btn btn-mdb-color btn-rounded float-left waves-effect waves-light">
        <span>Choose file</span>
        <input type="file">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Please note that the order of the CSS styles matters